# What is the probability of getting the first red marble at the fifth try?

Tags: math, probability

The problem sounds like this:
There are 8 white marbles and 10 red marbles in a bowl. Each action consists of taking one marble from the bowl and putting it back into the bowl. The question is: What is the probability that at the FIFTH time you are taking a marble out of the bowl, this would be the FIRST red marble that you took?

I tried to simplify a bit this problem and thinking only of the SECOND time. Therefore, I think the answer would be 8/18*10/18. (The probability of having the first one white and the second one red.) Could be this extended to the FIFTH case as well? (8/18)^4*10/18? I am not sure if I am missing something or not.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this a question about software or computing? It sounds more like a mathematics / statistics question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: ...hmmm... make a small code for simulating this...and it might become a programming question.

Comment: Didn't know exactly where should be asked?

Answer (score 1):

This is a `geometric aleatory variable` (let's call it X) because you have a succession of N independent Bernoulli aleatory variables, with probability of success `10/18`, so you have:

```
P(X=5) = (1-10/18)^4 * (10/18)
```

Because if you have a geometric aleatory variable `Y` with probability of success `p` then:

```
P(Y=k) = [(1-p)^(k-1)]*p
```